# Calculate First Year Base Rent using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a way to calculate an initial rent per UOM, which is a rent for the first year per unit of surface (lets say square feet), given a list of rent rent periods. The periods may start in the middle of a calendar year and change terms several times before the end of the lease (Example 1). Terms may also overlap (as in example 2):  Here's the 2 situations, where the result uses the terms in green for the final calculation:

[image]

[image]

I'm looking for a way to do this in SNOWFLAKE. Thanks.

Here's the sample data from above examples:

```html
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE RENTDATA
(
    EXAMPLE_DEAL INT,
    AMOUNT DECIMAL (15,2),
    SURFACE DOUBLE,
    TERM_START DATE,
    TERM_END DATE
);    

INSERT INTO RENTDATA VALUES (1,1300.00, 1600, '2018-08-01', '2019-05-31');
INSERT INTO RENTDATA VALUES (1,1177.60, 1600, '2019-06-01', '2020-05-31');
INSERT INTO RENTDATA VALUES (1,1212.92, 1600, '2020-06-01', '2021-05-31');
INSERT INTO RENTDATA VALUES (1,1249.32, 1600, '2021-06-01', '2022-05-31');
INSERT INTO RENTDATA VALUES (2,3000.00, 2465, '2023-11-01', '2024-10-31');
INSERT INTO RENTDATA VALUES (2,-3000.00,2465, '2023-11-01', '2024-04-30');
INSERT INTO RENTDATA VALUES (2,3090.00, 2465, '2024-11-01', '2025-10-31');
INSERT INTO RENTDATA VALUES (2,3183.00, 2465, '2025-11-01', '2026-10-31');
```

Comment: No idea how you arrive at some of those numbers, perhaps try to explain the calculations necessary, plus also tell us what it is that you want as the actual result.  Also provide some sample data in a reusable format (e.g. a text table, or sql inserts) - not images.  I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks @AdrianMaxwell, I added more explanations (in the last line of each example) and sql inserts for the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this requirement needs to deal with overlaps and a variable number of months for each deal within the first year I suggest generating a set of rows per month then matching the wanted deals against those months. This approach will enable a simple sum of amount/surfcae as the rows represent the number of months. In Postgres the following query matches your 2 examples:

```
WITH date_range AS (
  SELECT generate_series(
           date_trunc('month', (SELECT MIN(TERM_START) FROM RENTDATA)),
           date_trunc('month', (SELECT MAX(TERM_END) FROM RENTDATA)),
           '1 month'::interval
         )::date AS month
    )
    , deal_date_range
AS (
    SELECT
          EXAMPLE_DEAL
        , MIN(TERM_START) AS start_at
        , MIN(TERM_START) + INTERVAL '12 month' - INTERVAL '1 day' AS end_at
    FROM RENTDATA
    GROUP BY EXAMPLE_DEAL
    )
    , monthly_rentdata
AS (
    SELECT
          r.EXAMPLE_DEAL
        , r.AMOUNT
        , r.SURFACE
    FROM RENTDATA r
    JOIN date_range d ON d.month BETWEEN r.TERM_START AND r.TERM_END
    JOIN deal_date_range dr ON r.EXAMPLE_DEAL = dr.EXAMPLE_DEAL
                           AND r.TERM_START < dr.end_at
                           AND r.TERM_END > dr.start_at
                           AND d.month < dr.end_at
    )
SELECT EXAMPLE_DEAL
    , SUM(AMOUNT / SURFACE) AS subtotal
FROM monthly_rentdata
GROUP BY EXAMPLE_DEAL
ORDER BY EXAMPLE_DEAL
```

| example_deal | subtotal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9.59700000000000000000 |
| 2 | 7.3022312373225150 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2mU2nT_g)

For Snowflake I think the only change will be how the date range is formed:

```
WITH date_range AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(month, SEQ4(), DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', (SELECT MIN(TERM_START) FROM RENTDATA))) AS month
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => (DATEDIFF('month', (SELECT MIN(TERM_START) FROM RENTDATA), (SELECT MAX(TERM_END) FROM RENTDATA)) + 1)))
    )
    , deal_date_range
AS (
    SELECT
          EXAMPLE_DEAL
        , MIN(TERM_START) AS start_at
        , MIN(TERM_START) + INTERVAL '12 month' - INTERVAL '1 day' AS end_at
    FROM RENTDATA
    GROUP BY EXAMPLE_DEAL
    )
    , monthly_rentdata
AS (
    SELECT
          r.EXAMPLE_DEAL
        , r.AMOUNT
        , r.SURFACE
    FROM RENTDATA r
    JOIN date_range d ON d.month BETWEEN r.TERM_START AND r.TERM_END
    JOIN deal_date_range dr ON r.EXAMPLE_DEAL = dr.EXAMPLE_DEAL
                           AND r.TERM_START < dr.end_at
                           AND r.TERM_END > dr.start_at
                           AND d.month < dr.end_at
    )
SELECT EXAMPLE_DEAL
    , SUM(AMOUNT / SURFACE) AS subtotal
FROM monthly_rentdata
GROUP BY EXAMPLE_DEAL
ORDER BY EXAMPLE_DEAL
```

but I'm not able to test this.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.  The only problem I had in the Snowflake code is the Generator param needs to be a constant, so I got this message: 

argument 1 to function GENERATOR needs to be constant, found '(CAST(DATE_DIFFDATEINMONTHS('2018-08-01', '2026-10-31') AS NUMBER(9,0))) + 1'. 

No problem though, I replaced it with a constant 2400, which will ensure proper functioning of this code the next 200 years ;)

Comment: Great, good feedback. Thanks.